# Find and rank the 5 days with the highest score (some days have the same score)

Tags: sorting, date, google-sheets, transpose, rank

The data has the format below. (1st row is the date, 2nd row the score.) Some days have the same score.

| Date | 6-Oct | 7-Oct | 8-Oct | 9-Oct | 10-Oct | 11-Oct | 12-Oct | 13-Oct | 14-Oct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Score | 23 | 34 | 21 | 12 | 19 | 25 | 35 | 24 | 21 |

I'm trying to create a formula that will give me the dates of the top 5 scoring days.

| Rank | Date | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ? | 35 |
| 2 | ? | 34 |
| 3 | ? | 34 |
| 4 | ? | 25 |
| 5 | ? | 23 |

I created a formula using `index`, `match` and `large` however it does not work when 2 days have the same score.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in google sheets (as tagged):

```
=SORTN(TRANSPOSE(B1:J2); 5;; 2; )
```

[image]